# Look for AlarmManager impact on battery?

Tags: android, repeatingalarm

I have a process I'm running once a minute on my device. It's really only that fast because while debugging I'm bored of waiting any longer than that. Once a minute it calls my code that runs a web request and some sqlite entries and does some work that may run the battery down pretty fast. Since I'm running 4.2.2 (specifically Cyanogenmod nightlies) I have access to System > Battery where I can get a good breakdown on what apps are using my battery. What process should I expect to see these AlarmManager calls using battery for? AlarmManager? My app? Android System? I guess it comes down to me not knowing who the parent process is when an AlarmManager interval indicates it's time to process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb to dump information to know what other processes or apps are using alarmManager

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
```